Does any BFS (Basic feasible soln.) has only two adjacent BFS, irrespective of the # of structural constraints, and the number of decision variables?
Have seen two solved examples, using graphical approach, of LPP, using two decision variables. The first one had two structural constraints, and the second had three structural constraints.
In each of the cases, there were only two adjacent BFS (Basic Feasible Solutions) to each of the BFS, in the feasible convex region.
Wanted to check if using the algebraic approach, any BFS for a LPP, can have  more than two adjacent BFS. This doubt arose, as wanted to solve algebraically, the two LPPs; before moving on to the simplex method.
The first LPP is:
Maximize $Z = 6x_1 + 5x_2,$ subject to structural constraints: $C1: x_1 + x_2 \leq 5, C2: 3x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 12,$ and the obvious non-negativity constraints: $C3: x_1\geq 0, C4: x_2\geq 0.$
For the algebraic approach, need add two slack variables, corresponding to the two structural constraints, i.e. $x_3, x_4\geq 0.$
The augmented LPP is given as:
Maximize $Z = 6x_1 + 5x_2 +0.x_3 + 0.x_4,$ subject to structural constraints: $C1: x_1 + x_2 + x_3= 5, C2: 3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_4 = 12,$ and the obvious non-negativity constraints: $C3: x_1\geq 0, C4: x_2\geq 0, C5: x_3\geq 0, C6: x_4\geq 0.$
It has the list of BFS given by: $A:(0,0,5,12), B:(0,5,0,2), C:(2,3,0,0), D:(4,0,1,0).$ 
Each BFS has only two adjacent BFS, as shown below:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\, & BFS   & Adjacent-BFS & Shared - Edge & \\\hline
1    & A & B & C4\\
     &   & D & C3 \\ \hline
2    & B & A & C4 \\
     &   & C & C1 \\ \hline
3    & C & B & C1 \\
     &   & D & C2 \\\hline 
4    & D & A & C3 \\
     &   & C & C2 \\\hline 
\end{array}$$
The second LPP is given on page $28,$ of the book titled: introduction to Mathematical Programming, by Lieberman, Hillier.
It is given as:
There are two products, and three plants. The three structural constraints represent the three constraints on the number of hours available per week, at each plant; and the number of hours needed by each batch (measure of units) of the two products, per week, at the given plants.
The first structural constraint ($C1$) is that each batch of product $1$ needs $1$ hour per week, of production time in plant $1,$ whereas only $4$ hours of production time per week is available at plant $1.$
The second constraint ($C2$) is that each batch of product 2 needs 2 hours per week, of production time in plant $2,$ whereas only $12$ hours of production time per week is available at plant $2.$
The third structural constraint ($C3$) is that each batch of product $1$ needs $3$ hours per week, and product $2$ needs $2$ hours per week of production time in plant $3;$ whereas the plant $3$ has only $18$ hours of production time per week.
The formulated LPP is: 
Maximize $Z = 3x_1 + 5x_2,$ subject to structural constraints: $C1: x_1 \leq 4, C2: 2x_2 \leq 12, C3: 3x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 18,$ and the obvious non-negativity constraints: $C4: x_1\geq 0, C5: x_2\geq 0.$
For the algebraic approach, need add three slack variables, corresponding to the three structural constraints, i.e. $x_3, x_4, x_5\geq 0.$
The augmented LPP is: Maximize $Z = 3x_1 + 5x_2 + 0.x_3 + 0.x_4 + 0.x_5,$ subject to structural constraints: $C1: x_1 + x_3 = 4, C2: 2x_2 + x_4 = 12, C3: 3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_5 = 18,$  and the non-negativity constraints: $C4: x_1\geq 0, C5: x_2\geq 0, C6: x_3\geq 0, C7: x_4\geq 0, C8: x_5\geq 0.$
It has the list of BFS given by: $A: (0,0,5,12,18), B: (0,6,4,0,6), C:(2,6,2,0,0), D:(4,3,0,6,0).$
Each BFS has only two adjacent points, as shown below:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\, & BFS   & Adjacent-BFS & Shared - Edge & \\\hline
1    & A & B & C5\\
     &   & E & C4 \\ \hline
2    & B & A & C5 \\
     &   & C & C2 \\ \hline
3    & C & B & C2 \\
     &   & D & C3 \\\hline 
4    & D & C & C3 \\
     &   & E & C2 \\\hline 
5    & E & A & C1 \\
     &   & D & C2 \\\hline 
\end{array}$$
In order to get instead of a pentagonal feasible convex region, a hexagonal one. This was done to check if that changes the number of adjacent BFS, for the tweaked problem. 
For that tried to modify the second LPP, by adding fourth structural constraint ($C4$), to the second problem, by adding another plant $4.$ It has $20$ hours per week available, and each batch of product $1$ needs $4$ hours of production time per week; while each batch of the product $2$ needs $3$ hours of production time per week.
On adding the above additional constraint $C4: 4x_1 + 3x_2 \leq 20,$ have the modified LPP:
Maximize $Z = 3x_1 + 5x_2 + 0.x_3 + 0.x_4 + 0.x_5 + 0.x_6,$ subject to structural constraints: $C1: x_1 + x_3 = 4, C2: 2x_2 + x_4 = 12, C3: 3x_1 + 2x_2 + x_5=18, C4: 4x_1 + 3x_2 +x_6 =25,$  and the non-negativity constraints: $C5: x_1\geq 0, C6: x_2\geq 0, C7: x_3\geq 0, C8: x_4\geq 0, C9: x_5\geq 0, C10: x_6\geq 0.$
It has the list of BFS given by: $A:(0,0,4,12,18,25), B:(0,6,4,0,6,7), C:(7/4,6,9/4,0,3/4,0), D:(4,3,0,6,0,0), E:(4,0,0,12,6,9).$
Though expected to add another edge to the polygon formed in the feasible region, but as the two constraints : $C3, C4$ intersect at the same BFS $C,$ so failed to add extra edge. 
The result is only an improvement of the value of BFS point $C,$ as get instead a slightly smaller value of $x_1$ there; this is accompanied by a change in the shared constraint boundary between the BFS $C,\text{&} D$ to $C4$ instead of the earlier $C3.$ 
Also, each BFS has still two adjacent BFS, as shown in the table below.
Am sorry for not able to find a problem that adds the number of sides of the convex polygon, by one. Though, still request help, on the topic stated in the title.  But, would continue to search for a suitable LPP, whose convex region has at least six sides, or more.
Each BFS still has only two adjacent points, as shown below:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\, & BFS   & Adjacent-BFS & Shared - Edge & \\\hline
1    & A & B & C6\\
     &   & E & C5 \\ \hline
2    & B & A & C6 \\
     &   & C & C2 \\ \hline
3    & C & B & C2 \\
     &   & D & C4 \\\hline 
4    & D & C & C4 \\
     &   & E & C1 \\\hline 
5    & E & A & C5 \\
     &   & D & C1 \\\hline 
\end{array}$$

No, this is not the case. Take a simpler example where each basic feasible solution has only one adjacent basic feasible solution: $\min_x \ x$ such that $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Adding a slack variable $s$, the problem becomes $\min_x \ x$ such that $x-1+s=0$, $0 \geq x$ and $s \geq 0$. The basic feasible solution are $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Also, since you are talking about basic feasible solution, the objective function is not needed.

@MarcDinh Thanks, but seems am correct, as you did not present any example stating higher number of adjacent BFS, than two. Also, am unable to understand how the double inequality given by you, gave rise to: $x\leq 0.$ Expected $x\geq 0.$ Also, seems that second axis ($y-$ axis) has been taken as that of $s.$ Such usage of a slack variable, to determine the feasible region, has not been seen by me before. Kindly detail, and provide some reference, for such usage of the slack variable.

Sorry, the constraint should be $x \geq 0$ and not $x \leq 0$ and you were right. I only gave an example that there is not always 2 adjacent basic feasible solutions. If you want more, take a tetrahedron (for instance) in the positive orthant of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and write the tetrahedron as linear inequalities. You should have 4 inequalities as there are 4 facets. Then each vertex is linked to 3 other vertices.

But in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is not possible to have more than 2 adjacents basic feasible solutions because the feasible region is a convex polygon. But already in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can obtain a basic feasible solution with as many adjacent basic feasible solutions as you want. I think it is quite easy to construct if you think geometrically.

@MarcDinh Very much thanks for that. Am confused as how to prove the same algebraically, in $\mathbb{R^3}.$ Will the Guass-Jordan elimination be a suitable tool to show algebraically that more than $2$ adjacent BFS exist in $\mathbb{R^3},$ using a system of $3$ linear equations in $3$ unknowns? If yes, how. If not, please tell of some way. If possible, state an answer for the same; as then it would be more detailed.

I don't think you need to look at anything algebraically, necessarily; pick a three-variable problem, draw the feasible region and you'll probably have an example.  (I mean, if you pick the simplest possible constraints $0\leq x_i \leq n_i$ for some constants $n_i$, your feasible region will just be a box with a corner at the origin, and the origin will have three adjacent neighbors on the box: $(n_1, 0, 0)$, $(0,n_2,0)$, and $(0,0,n_3)$.)
